# Google Cloud Composer v2 health-check seems to be false negative/flaky

Tags: google-cloud-composer

We created a Composer v2 environment to migrate from Google Cloud Composer v1.
All DAG code was adjusted and we are using the to this date newest available image `composer-2.0.0-preview.5-airflow-2.1.4`.

We noticed that even though the CPU is relaxed and memory is plenty, the `Web server health` is flaky (red / green alternating every couple of minute on the environment monitoring page).

For a test I removed the K8s health check on the webserver pod in K8s (and the startup probe as well). I then found that there is a call coming from the IP of the `airflow-monitoring` pod (`10.63.129.6`), and shortly thereafter the gunicorn process receives a HUP:

```
airflow-webserver 10.63.129.6 - - [17/Nov/2021:12:56:03 +0000] "GET /_ah/health HTTP/1.1" 200 187 "-" "python-requests/2.24.0"
airflow-webserver [2021-11-17 12:56:05 +0000] [57] [INFO] Handling signal: hup
airflow-webserver [2021-11-17 12:56:05 +0000] [57] [INFO] Hang up: Master
airflow-webserver [2021-11-17 12:56:05 +0000] [1083] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1083
airflow-webserver [2021-11-17 12:56:05 +0000] [1084] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1084
airflow-webserver [2021-11-17 12:56:05 +0000] [1051] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1051)
airflow-webserver [2021-11-17 12:56:05 +0000] [1052] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1052)
airflow-webserver [2021-11-17 12:56:05 +0000] [1085] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1085
airflow-webserver [2021-11-17 12:56:05 +0000] [1086] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1086
airflow-webserver [2021-11-17 12:56:07 +0000] [57] [WARNING] Worker with pid 1052 was terminated due to signal 15
airflow-webserver [2021-11-17 12:56:07 +0000] [57] [WARNING] Worker with pid 1051 was terminated due to signal 15
```

This happens every minute, so webserver is responding slowly.
As the `airflow-monitoring` pod is running in a protected namespace in GKEAutopilot, I am not sure how to debug this further.

**Update:**
It seems like there are two things at play here, one looks like a race-condition between the `gcs-syncd` pod and the `webserver`:

```
Removing file:///home/airflow/gcs/plugins/operators/__pycache__/trigger_emarsys_event_operator.cpython-38.pyc
{webserver_command.py:217} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/airflow/gcs/plugins/operators/__pycache__/trigger_emarsys_event_operator.cpython-38.pyc'
{webserver_command.py:218} ERROR - Shutting down webserver
```

Comment: Can you check your `[webserver]reload_on_plugin_change` config option? \
Can you try to disable it?

Comment: @MateuszH thank you, this solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the reloading of the webserver, when plugin changes are detected, resolved the situation. Each time when the gcs-sync happened this was the thing that triggered the restart. Thanks to @MateuszH for the tip!

```
[webserver]
reload_on_plugin_change=False
```

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#reload-on-plugin-change

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured `core:default_timezone` airflow configuration, environment health status is just a metric and it will not have any impact on the actual job/tasks execution.

You can ignore the health status or you can remove the configuration to accept default UTC timezone.

This is because Composer runs a liveness DAG named airflow_monitoring every 5 minutes and reports environment health as follow:

- When the DAG run finishes successfully the health status is True.
- If the DAG run fails, the health status is False.
- If the DAG does not finish, Composer polls the DAG’s status every 5 minutes and reports False if the one-hour timeout occurs.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense, but I still don't understand what is sending the HUP signal if this iust a monitoring service? The constant killing of gunicorn makes the environment unstable.

Comment: Well what can be happening is that if a worker is not terminating on its own quickly enough, its just terminated externally `(due to signal 15)`. And it might make your environment unstable.

Comment: Let me rephrase: The problem is that something is sending a HUP every minute to the unicorn process. This is causing a memory leak in the long run, which causes GKE to restart the container since its running over its memory limits. I would like to find out what is sending the HUP signal.

Comment: I see, what you can do is to create a new environment, and gradually make changes until you find the DAG/PyPI package that is causing issues or until the issue goes away.